# How I can move some registry resources from one tenant to another in WSO2 products?

Tags: registry, wso2, multi-tenant, wso2-esb

I want to move some registry stuff stored inside one tenant to another tenant in ESB 4.5.0.

So I decided to used the WSO2 Registry Browser in WSO2 Developer Studio 2.1.0, but I don´t see how I can do this. I can access to every resources and I try to export/import without success.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to move the registry resources from one tenant to another, the recommended approach is using the registry [check-in client](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance452/Running+Check-in+Client).

Currently this is shipped only with G-Reg, but you can use this feature by copying the checkin-client.jar and script to the relevant locations in your server (i.e. ESB)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way you can do is, 
when you are creating tenants ESB creating directory structure in "wso2esb-ESB4.5.0/repository/tenants" location. if you creates 2 tenants there's two directory created in above location. if you want to copy all stuffs created in one tenant to other tenant you have to copy all directories inside the "*ESB4.5.0/repository/tenants/tenant1" and paste it to new tenant directory in "ESB4.5.0/repository/tenants/tenant2" location.

Comment: thanks Chamara, but what about the registry information. All my sequences in ESB are stored in the registry, also my endpoints and xslt files. How I can move that?

Comment: Sequences also migrating with this. you will see your sequences located in "tenants/tenant1/synapse-configs/default/sequences".

Comment: ok, but this sequences are the static sequences not the dynamic sequences inside the registry, I checked this right now in one of my tenant, I can see in the file system the static sequences but not the dynamic sequences. My concern is related to this dynamic sequences and how i can export them from one registry to another registry

Comment: if you want to migrate registry info like dynamic sequence etc. you can use check-in client for that. hence this feature shipped with the wso2 governance registry you can use this feature like [1].[2] will explain how to use check-in client feature.   1.http://stackoverflow.com/a/13488508/1722586 2.http://wso2.org/project/registry/4.1.0/docs/user_guide/checkin_client.html