# WSO2 Governance registry - How to move from one server to another?

Tags: wso2, migrate

If I want to move the governance registry (including the data entered for services, associations/dependencies/comments/ratings/etc) from one server to another, how can I do that?

I see that the check-in-client can be used to migrate from one server to another for the files and the directory structure? How can I migrate the associated data for a service like associations/dependencies, etc

Comment: Can I use this solution to resolve my concern in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406977/how-i-can-move-some-registry-resources-from-one-tenant-to-another-in-wso2-produc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Associations and dependencies are included when you perform the migration using checkin client. At the moment it uses dump restore style restoration.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WSO2 Developer Studio, same functionality available in Developer Studio as well.

If you are using Registry Check-In client, you have to run it trough the console. But with Developer Studio, you can simply select a collection or a Resource in one Registry from Eclipse and instruct to Move or Copy that selected Resource or collection to another registry in Eclipse.

For more information follow [this](http://dist.wso2.org/products/developer-studio/2.1.0/docs/greg_user_guide.html#import)

/Harshana

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use check-in client for that. it's used to take a registry dump and restore to another registry.Could you elaborate why you want to do this? i don't have clear idea with your exact requirement. please find the more information of check-in client [here](http://wso2.org/project/registry/4.1.0/docs/user_guide/checkin_client.html).